# Angular 4 w/ AngularFire 2 and Auth Guard

Tags: angular, authentication, firebase, angular2-routing, angularfire2

I have started creating a simple app that has a pre-login and post-login section.  I'm using FireBase (with AngularFire2) as my authentication provider and I'd like to "Guard" the post-login pages using `canActivate()` in an auth guard service.

My problem is, I don't know the order or placement of each piece of code.  I've simplified what I have below:

app.component.ts

```
constructor(private auth: Authentication) {
    this.auth.subscribe();
}
```

authentication.ts

```
export class Authentication {

    state: Observable<firebase.User>;
    user: any;
    isLoggedIn: boolean;

    constructor(private afAuth: AngularFireAuth, private router: Router) {
        this.state = afAuth.authState;
    }

    subscribe() {
        this.state.subscribe((auth) => {
            if(auth) {
                this.user = auth;
                console.log(this.user);
                this.isLoggedIn = true;
                return true;
            } else {
                this.isLoggedIn = false;
                return false;
            }
        });
    }

    login() {
        this.afAuth.auth.signInWithPopup(new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider());
    }

    logout() {
        this.afAuth.auth.signOut();
    }
}
```

auth-guard.service.ts

```
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {

    constructor(private auth: Authentication, private router: Router) {}

    canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {
        let url: string = state.url;
        return this.checkLogin(url);
    }

    checkLogin(url: string): boolean {
        if(this.auth.isLoggedIn) {
            console.log("Can Activate True");
            return true;
        } else {
            console.log("Can Activate False");
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Right now it's pretty much working.  When I start fresh, I get a screen with all of my links on the top of the screen, a login and a logout button.  When I click on the links at the top of the screen, I get the console.log saying "Can Activate False", which is perfect.  I'm not logged in yet.

When I log in, then try the links again, I get the "Can Activate True" which is also perfect.

When I log out again, and without refreshing, I try to click on the links above and I don't get any console.log back.

I feel like something is wrong with my subscribe or just everything in general.  What could I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> {
  return this.af.authState.map(auth => {
    if (isNullOrUndefined(auth)) {
      this.router.navigate(['/login']);
      return false;
    } else {
      return true;
    }
  });
}
```

It is much easier. No messing around with aync and sync stuff.

Comment: I'm getting an error `Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Observable<User>'`.  I'm taking a look into it

Comment: this is with angularfire2 4.0.0-rc.0

Comment: Correct, that's what I'm using: `"angularfire2": "^4.0.0-rc.0",`

Comment: and firebase ^3.9.0

Comment: Try adding `import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';`

Comment: So, it seems to act the same.  When I start fresh (not logged in) If I try to go to the guarded pages, it keeps me on the login page.  When I log in, I get a good auth, and I can click on one of the guarded pages.  I use a console.log in your statement (above the return) and I see that a single time.  When I click on another link, I don't get the console.log again, nor when I log out.  It's like the `return false` (or something) is making the guard stop working

Comment: I think I found the problem - I wasn't redirecting on logout, so I was technically still in the guarded components when logged out.  I'm not sure if this is the real answer, but when I `router.navigate([]);` to the login page, I'm not able to access the auths anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the AngularFireAuthGuard for that case.

Add the lines below to your routing.module.ts:

```
const redirectUnauthorizedToLogin = () => redirectUnauthorizedTo(['login']);

    path: '',
    component: UserDashboardComponent,
    //data: { title: 'user.dashboard' },
    canActivate: [AngularFireAuthGuard],
    data: {authGuardPipe: redirectUnauthorizedToLogin}
```

This code-snipped will do a redirect if the User is not authenticated. And furthermore its easy to implement.